# How to combine multiple similar datasets into one in Kedro dynamically?

Tags: python, kedro

I use Kedro to run pipelines for multiple models that each generate a CSV file with the same schema. However, I need to combine each of the generated CSV files into one and do some post processing which will be my final output.
This is what my catalog looks like:

```
catalog.yml
model1.output:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: ${data_path}/output/model1/output.csv

model2.output:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: ${data_path}/output/model2/output.csv

model3.output:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: ${data_path}/output/model3/output.csv

final_output:
  type: pandas.CSVDataSet
  filepath: ${data_path}/output/final_output.csv
  layer: output
```

I can define my node such that each output is called individually and combined, like the following:

```
node.py
def combine(model_1_output, model_2_output, model_3_output):
    ...
```

However, I would like to do that dynamically, where I define in my parameters a list of valid models, and only the datasets of those model outputs are loaded. This will be beneficial in case future models are added, or I need to run a subset of all my models selectively.

```
parameters.yml
valid_models:
  - model1
  - model2
```

Is there a way where this can be done? I've tried using both pipeline and node hooks, however, I couldn't use either of them to solve this particular problem. It also seems like I can't access the global_parameters where my ${data_path} is defined directly in the node so that I can read the required datasets that way.

Edit:
Turns out that I can access the ${data_path} global parameter by defining it in the `base/parameters.yml`, and defining my path as a string:

```
node.py
def combine(params):
    base_path = params[data_path]
    for model in valid_models:
        data = pd.read_csv(f"base_path/output/{model}/output.csv")
```

However, I am still not sure if this is the best approach, and can kedro's functions be used to implement this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

[`PartitionedDataSet`](https://docs.kedro.org/en/stable/data/kedro_io.html#partitioned-dataset) is what you're looking for:

> `PartitionedDataSet` can recursively load/save all or specific files from a given location.

For example:

```yaml
my_partitioned_dataset:
  type: PartitionedDataSet
  path: base_path/output/  # path to the location of partitions
  dataset: pandas.CSVDataSet  # shorthand notation for the dataset which will handle individual partitions
```

Comment: However, I am not partitioning my data set. I need to combine three different datasets into one single dataset, which will be overwritten every time my pipeline runs.

Comment: @NandhaKumar if they have the same schema they can be treated as different partitions of the same dataset. Could you try it in case it works? Otherwise we can find another solution